# Multi threading in windows phone C#?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, windows-phone-7, notifications

Multi threading in windows phone C# ?

How to do multithreading when i call a wcf service . One thread should call service and one thread should show processing.

Answer (score 1):

I've never programmed for windows phone but I have a fair bit of experience with c# and a quick google search shows windows phone has support for BackgroundWorkers. I would suggest using that for your time consuming task, you can even get a progress update. Check this out for an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403(v=vs.105).aspx

It's what I use when calling a WCF service from a WPF app

Answer (score 0):

WP7 has a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class that can help you.

It has the `WorkerReportsProgress` property and `ProgressChanged` event that can inform you about its progress.

Answer (score 0):

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) seems like a good choice given your description of the problem. It is pretty easy to work with. But it is also worth mentioning that there are other methods to do multithreading on Windows Phone 7 such as a ThreadPool.

I can recommend checking out this question (and answers) which describe the possible options:
[Background Threads in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057139/background-threads-in-windows-phone)